# Data entered offline does not synchronize when going back online

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Some users report that they create offline content and when they go online they lose their data. They just disappear.

I do not know where to start, in my tests this does not occur.

Is there an authentication problem? I use today the form E-mail and password.

I'm using minSdkVersion 16 and compile 'com.google.firebase: firebase-auth: 10.2.1'

I mentioned Auth, why it is not clear how the firebase behaves when the user loses authentication. Let's assume that it loses authentication and inserts new data (after losing authentication), what does firebase do?

1 - Block the insertion - if this is the behavior, my problem will not be the tightening, because the data is inserted and I can see it in the APP.

2 - Does not block the insertion, but when it is online this data will be lost (it is my suspicion)

3 - Does not block the insertion, puts the insert in the queue and updates the base (this is what I hope, because if the user for an unexpected reason lose the offline authentication I will not have to authenticate again until it goes online).

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for apps to go offline, go to the background, and eventually killed by Android to save resources.  If you want to persist any data written while the app is offline and is later killed, you should [enable persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities), which is off by default:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

The written data will be synchronized when the app is launched again and comes online.

Transactions are not supported when offline.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but offline mode is already enabled, unfortunately this is not the solution. It is not always that it happens, it is random.

Comment: If there is a bug with offline sync, you should file a bug report with specific repro details.  Persistence and synchronization won't have anything to do with authentication.

Comment: There are no errors when saving the dice offiline, while offiline is okay, is displayed after inserting successfully. The problem is that getting online some.
I'm trying to simulate the problem, but as I said it is random. I edited and put the Downey on the Auth.

Answer (score 0):

From the Firebase docs  [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?authuser=0), it says:

> Any transactions that are performed while the app is offline, are
>   queued. Once the app regains network connectivity, the transactions
>   are sent to the Realtime Database server.

But then immediately after that Firebase issues a warning:

> Even with persistence enabled, transactions are not persisted across
>   app restarts. So you cannot rely on transactions done offline being
>   committed to your Firebase Realtime Database. To provide the best user
>   experience, your app should show that a transaction has not been saved
>   into your Firebase Realtime Database yet, or make sure your app
>   remembers them manually and executes them again after an app restart.

Now I'm not too sure the exact scenario your users are going through, but I do have a couple of suggestions on how to deal with this issue.

Firstly, since the chances of transactions being persisted when the device is offline and the app goes to the background are very low, you could just as well check for network connectivity before allowing user updates in your app. This is an easy way out of course, but it does the trick.

Also, you could go with Firebase's advice and attach a listener to every upload and mark the offline content as "x" (not a good choice admittedly) or something to indicate that the content is not uploaded yet, in your UI. Something similar to the WhatsApp clock icon that shows on messages that haven't been sent. Then when your app resumes or restarts, let it check for all unsent content and re-upload them.

Thirdly, just like in the second case, you can just put an error message on that content, but this time tell your users to resend them on restart.

I basically just summarized all that the docs said, but at least this should put you on the right path to fixing this.

Comment: This is terrible. Firebase then does not have offiline support as it advertises, as it is partial.
Its 1 suggestion is impractical for business, not every place has access to the network at all times. The 2 alternative would work if Firebase provided me with status of each changed data / or not
The 3 alternative would have to penalize my user making him repeat an action.
I am very disappointed! So long developing my app based on a solution that does not solve, it only works fully online.

Comment: Never meant to paint firebase badly though. It's quite efficient, as the offline support is super-helpful when it comes to viewing data offline and even in uploading data offline as well. It's more of android destroying the task when the offline app is in the background that poses an issue.

Comment: I do not believe it is an android problem, since in the APP folder it does not mess in extreme case of lack of space. I'm talking about lack of access for just over a few hours. The Firebase should block the offiline insert or ensure that the data will be inserted. At the very least, Firebase should make that clearer for developers, perhaps a way to see what has not yet been synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

try - 
[Enabling Offline Capabilities on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

Comment: You can try this for offline caching - http://www.snappydb.com/ and make a wrapper class which will check and insert data during offline

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that's not the point. I wanted to be sure of what's going on with Firebase, pretend to understand and take action (this could be this tip you passed).